# How do I only keep the first line of text in a multi-line cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have thousands of cells that contain three lines in each cell.
I only want to keep the first line and discard the rest.
For example, I only want to keep the "I need to eat to live" sentence.

Cell A1

```
I need to eat to live.
I live to eat.
I love to eat and live.
```

I hope my explanation makes sense :)

Thank you.

Comment: I just realised the example is shown as one line structure.

Comment: Kindly imagine that each sentence is separated into rows. I think the formatting does not allow me to make it look like I have three rows/lines.

Comment: By rows, do you mean line break within the cell ?

Comment: Yes, line break is the word I was looking for PeterH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a helper column, and use the below formula in the top row:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(10),A1)))
```

Then drag this down the whole column.

Copy all of the helper column, and paste the values.
You can then delete column A.

It works by finding `CHAR(10)`, which is the first line break, then takes everything to the left of this.

Leaving you with just the first line form each Cell.

Comment: Thank you very much PeterH. You saved the day dear unsung hero. Have an awesome day ahead :)

Comment: @Nazrul3000 happy to help, and welcome to super user ! you can accept the answer as correct by clicking the arrow to the left of the answer.

Comment: How do I go if I want to retain the second (remove the first and third) and also retain the third (remove the first and second) line breaks?

Comment: @Nazrul3000 I will update the answer later to include how to do these as well

Answer (score 1):

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Selection, _
                        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                        Other:=True, _
                        OtherChar:= Chr(10), _
                        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
                                         Array(2, 9), _
                                         Array(3, 9))
```

**UPDATE**

> A little more information would be helpful

Create new macros (VBA editor - Add module - create subroutine with some name, or Macros - enter some name - Create, then insert this code into macro body). Then select a cell, a column, or a range containing 1 column only, with cells which need above truncation, and run created macro.

If some cell(s) contains more than 3 rows of text, macro will ask you for replacing of another cells content - cancel to protect your data.

You may freely edit the text and increase max possible rows in a cell by adding more values to FieldInfo.

Comment: A little more information would be helpful

Comment: @Worthwelle Done.